# Ant: проверить какие классы изменены с последней ревизии git

Tags: git, ant, git-status

Как можно с помощью ant'a сделать проверку состояния рабочей копии, и, если изменения не касаются некоторых классов, которые будут указанных в файле параметров, то выполнять commit в репозиторий git.
Как сделать коммит ant'ом я знаю:

```
<exec executable="git" dir = "${repos.dir}">
    <arg value="add"/>
    <arg value="*"/>
</exec>
<exec executable="git" dir = "${repos.dir}">
    <arg value="commit"/>m
    <arg value="-m"/>
    <arg value="${commit.name}"/>
</exec>
```

Но как мне проверить были изменены именно нужные мне классы или нет?

Comment: какое отношение вопрос имеет к использованию `ant` ?

Comment: @jmu автор хочет выполнять `git log` с помощью ant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В java файлы имеют теже названия, что и классы, которые находятся внутри них (есть конечно вложенные классы, но пока не будем о них).

Что бы узнать, какие файлы поменялись, нужно выполнить `git status`. Этот вывод слишком "обильный", но если добавить параметр `--porcelain`, то вывод станет заметно чище. Теперь все модифицированные файлы будут иметь `M`, а новые файлы - `AM`.

Теперь следующий этап. Нужно заготовить файл, который будет содержать список классов (по одному имени класса на строку). пусть имя этого файла будет class.lst.

После этого вырисовывается команда

```
git status --porcelain | grep ' M ' | grep -f class.lst -c
```

Результатом будет просто число, которое укажет количество классов, которые были модифицированы и находятся в списке.

А вот как это завернуть в ant - этого я уже не знаю. Да, это может не работать, если у Вас windows.

Но в этом случае у ant есть один козырь в рукаве. Для него можно писать свои задачи, причем на [java](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html). А это позволяет разгуляться и сделать свою, правильную задачу. При этом java код не должен даже запускать git - его запустит ant, а вывод передаст уже задаче.

Comment: Вместо  `--porcelain` можно `-s`.